# Property not defined while extends from BaseUser at FOSUserBundle

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle, symfony-2.7, symfony2-easyadmin

I have this User entity extends from BaseUser:

```
namespace PDOneBundle\Entity;

use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use PDOneBundle\Classes\Form\Validator\Constraints as GdcaAssert;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation as Gedmo;
use Gedmo\Timestampable\Traits\TimestampableEntity;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\AdvancedUserInterface;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 * @ORM\Table(name="fos_user")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="PDOneBundle\Entity\Repository\UserRepository")
 * @Gedmo\SoftDeleteable(fieldName="deletedAt", timeAware=false)
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{
    /*
     * Hook timestampable behavior
     * updates createdAt, updatedAt fields
     */
    use TimestampableEntity;

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Company", inversedBy="users", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="company_id", referencedColumnName="ID")
     */
    protected $company;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Company", mappedBy="admins", cascade={"persist"})
     */
    protected $companies;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Project", mappedBy="admins", cascade={"persist"})
     */
    protected $projects;

    // methods goes here
}
```

I am using also EasyAdminBundle and any time I try to add a new user from EasyAdmin I got the following error:

> Neither the property "expiresAt" nor one of the methods
>   "getExpiresAt()", "expiresAt()", "isExpiresAt()", "hasExpiresAt()",
>   "__get()" exist and have public access in class
>   "PDOneBundle\Entity\User".

Why? It is not supposed that those methods are extended from BaseUser? Why the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't look like there is a getter for property `expiresAt` : https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Model/User.php
I guess you could easily add your own getter in your extended `User` class if `EasyAdminBundle` requires it.

```
class User extends BaseUser
{
    // ...
    public function getExpiresAt() {
        return $this->expiresAt;
    }
    // ...
}
```

---

Looks like you could also define which properties `EasyAdminBundle` controls : https://github.com/javiereguiluz/EasyAdminBundle/blob/v1.2.1/Resources/doc/11-configuration-reference.md#advanced-configuration-with-custom-field-configuration